# flutter - time_range_picker package

Tags: flutter, time, range, picker

I managed to create a function (which I put in a TextButton) where you can see the Time_range_picker and choose the range.

I just can't show the result either in a text widget or in the button label.

```
class OpeningHours extends StatefulWidget {

  const OpeningHours({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
  State<OpeningHours> createState() => _OpeningHoursState();
}

class _OpeningHoursState extends State<OpeningHours> {
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: TextButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.penToSquare,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: Text(
              result.toString(),   // it does not work
              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 22,
              ),
            ),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                shadowColor: Colors.red,
                elevation: 18,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
            onPressed: () {
              pickTimeRange(context);
            },
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future pickTimeRange(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeRange? result = await showTimeRangePicker(context: context); 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should initialize the timer value like this `TimeRange? resultForPrint; // add this line` ,then you should update this value using `setSteate`

please check my code , it will work

```
class Oeffnungszeiten extends StatefulWidget {

  const Oeffnungszeiten({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
  State<Oeffnungszeiten> createState() => _OeffnungszeitenState();
}

class _OeffnungszeitenState extends State<Oeffnungszeiten> {

TimeRange? resultForPrint; // add this line

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: TextButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.penToSquare,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: Text(

///////////////////////// add this code

              resultForPrint == null
              ? "Hi Friend"
             : "${resultForPrint!.startTime.format(context)} , ${resultForPrint!.endTime.format(context)}",

/////////////////////////

              style: const TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 22,
              ),
            ),
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                shadowColor: Colors.red,
                elevation: 18,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
            onPressed: () {
              pickTimeRange(context);
            },
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future pickTimeRange(BuildContext context) async {
    final TimeRange? result = await showTimeRangePicker(context: context); 
 
//////////////////////////// add this code

     setState(() {
              resultForPrint = result;
            });

/////////////////////////

      }
    }
```

Comment: @JanitoJoseph **Thank you very much, you are my hero.**
I have one more question. Why is the result now "TimeOfDay(00:00)toTimeOfDay(00:00)" in the resultForPrint. I know that the TimeRange class does it that way, but how can I see the result without TimeOfDay, so only the numbers.

Comment: i liked that ( hero ) ............. ok here we go....

Comment: i edit the Answer , start time : resultForPrint!.startTime.format(context)  , end time : resultForPrint!.endTime.format(context)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. stupid question I know, but where should I insert the answer.

Comment: i edited this answer , so i added this code , please check my answer one more time , and you can see below the  "Hi Friend"

Comment: I'm so stupid I'm ashamed... it works :)))))))

Comment: are you new to stack over flow

Comment: obviously yes :)))))